# PHP upload csv file into array to server

Tags: php, arrays, csv, soap, upload

I am trying to upload a csv file with my php script, but it seems that only the first row is sent to the server. I  tried severals solutions as putting q loop while but all don't `while(! feof($handle)){ $data=fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","); ...}` but it crashes.

If someone else could help me.
Thanks.

**Here my php script**:

```
<?php
$URL = 'https://mutalyzer.nl/services/?wsdl';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mutalyzer SOAP client</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mutalyzer SOAP client</h1>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data']) {
    echo $_GET['data'];
    $variant = $_GET['data'];
    echo $variant;
    //$filename = basename($_FILES['data']['name']);
    $_FILES['data']['name']=$_GET['data'];
    $filename = basename( $_FILES['data']['name']);

    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

    /*while(! feof($handle)){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    //print_r($data);
    }*/
    //$encripData = base64_encode($variant);

    $NameChecker=$_GET['process'];
    echo '<h2>Result for '.htmlentities($variant).'</h2>';

   $options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client = new SoapClient($URL, $options);
//while(! feof($handle)){
//$data=fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
    $result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data' => $data[0], 'process' =>$NameChecker))
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;
               //print_r(array('data' => $data, 'process' =>$NameChecker));
//}

print_r($result);
}

?>

<h2>Submit job data file to MUTALYZER</h2>

<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
Input file:
</p>
<input name="data" type="file" id="data" />
<br/>
  Process :
<input type="text" size="10" name="process" id="process" value="NameChecker"/>
<br/>
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide details what error you get and WSDL of service you're calling? Just guessing - isn't a problem in `$data[0]` value in `$result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data' => $data[0], 'process' =>$NameChecker))->submitBatchJobResult;` (maybe it have to be `$data`)?

Comment: @MilanTomeš, Hi, I did the change $data[0] to $data I have these errors: `code`Use of undefined constant SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS - assumed 'SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS'``code` and also:`code`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown`code`

Answer (score 0):

try like this, below code works..

```
   <?php 
    // sample_file.csv file contains 35 rows.
    $row = 1; 
    $csv_array = array(); 
     if (($handle = fopen("C:\Users\develop2\Downloads\sample_file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $csv_array[] = $data;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    // here u can get the data in csv as an array with fulll rows..
    print_r($csv_array);
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Venkatesh Mani, I tried to use your code, but the server reponds: `Use of undefined constant SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS - assumed 'SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS'`

Comment: please refer this link https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008tKkIAI

Comment: hi, I have already checked your link. My SOAP is activated. The thing, it always takes only the first element in my array when submiting.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my source code. My only issue is the server gets only the last line of my array. There is something bad that I am doing but I don't know. here's my new source code:

```
<?php
$URL = 'https://mutalyzer.nl/services/?wsdl';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mutalyzer SOAP client</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mutalyzer SOAP client</h1>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data']) {

    $variant = $_GET['data'];


    $_FILES['data']['name']=$_GET['data'];
    $filename = basename( $_FILES['data']['name']);
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    //$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");


    $NameChecker=$_GET['process'];
    echo '<h2>Result for '.htmlentities($variant).'</h2>';

   $options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client = new SoapClient($URL, $options);
$data=array();
while(! feof($handle)){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000);

    $result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data' => $data[0], 'process' =>$NameChecker))
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;
               print_r(array('data' => $data, 'process' =>$NameChecker));
            }  
print_r($result); 
}

?>

<h2>Submit job data file to MUTALYZER</h2>

<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
Input file:
</p>
<input name="data" type="file" id="data" />
<br/>
  Process :
<input type="text" size="10" name="process" id="process" value="NameChecker"/>
<br/>
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```